# Bulk way to determine of all paths, which one exists (Possibly in one API Call)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of strings and want to check which of all those documents exist in my Firestore in two ways:

I am using Node Admin SDK:

```
import Server from '../../../../firebase/firebase_server_exports';

export const databaseEntryExists = async (paths: string[]): Promise<string> => {
  const promises = paths.map(
    (element) =>
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        Server.db
          .doc(element)
          .get()
          .then((doc) => resolve(doc.exists ? element : ''));
      })
  );
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  return results.includes(true) ? paths[results.indexOf(true)] : '';
};
```

Though this method works nicely, if I have 100 paths, I will be making 100 API calls which doesn't sound a good deal to me. Can someone suggest any Fierstore utility function or something like batch document fetching in order to reduce this to one API call?

Comment: if you are using http2 multiplexing, doing those 100 requests is pretty much the same as doing 1 request that triggeres 100 actions on the other end. You may actually get the benfit from the multiplex way that individual requests can fail and succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Node.js SDK, you can create `DocumentReference` objects for all IDs and then use `getAll()` to get them all in one go. See the [documentation for `getAll()` for an example](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#getAll).

This call does not exist in the client-side SDKs though, so the closest you  can get there is to combine up to 10 IDs in a single call by querying on [`FieldPath.documentId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldPath) and using the [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any). There is nothing to request