# How do you fetch a list of documents from a firestore collection

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

so there is a list named `List<String> lectures = [lec0, lec3, lec8]`, and All of the lectures are stored in a collection named **lectures**. How am I supposed to fetch only the given list of lectures?

Edit:
I've created an implementation as follows:

```dart
List<String> lectureList = [lec0, lec3, lec8]
 CollectionReference get lectures => _db.collection('lectures');
 Future<QuerySnapshot> getLectures({required List<String> lectureList}) async {
    return await lectures
        // FIXME: Check if this works or not
        .where(lectureList,
            arrayContains:
                FieldPath.documentId) // I guess this is kinda incorrect
        .orderBy('date')
        .get();
  }
```

Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Are those the ids of the lecture documents in the **lectures** collection?

Comment: yes, they are the id's

Answer (score 0):

The client-side SDKs for Firestore have no API to get a set of documents by their ID. The closest you can get there is to combine up to 10 IDs in a single call by querying on `FieldPath.documentId()` and using the `in` operator.

I recently answered a similar question for Node, so I recommend checking that out too:
[Bulk way to determine of all paths, which one exists (Possibly in one API Call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361601/bulk-way-to-determine-of-all-paths-which-one-exists-possibly-in-one-api-call/71363480#71363480)